# SUBMIT button value sent only when clicked

Tags: php, html, forms, request

I have the following web form:

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" onclick="submit()">
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>
```

So either clicking the submit button or the checkbox this form is submitted to process.php page. But submit's value named "search" is sent only when button clicked explicitly, not when checkbox is clicked. Unexpectedly for me. I expected that submitting the form with submit() command will send all parameters as well (including submit button's "search" parameter).
So in PHP code I cannot use:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])
```

to test if form was submitted, I have to use:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
```

Is this normal behaviour of submitt button?

Comment: If may also use if (!empty($_POST)) { .... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this the correct behavior.
The value of a submit input is only send when activated or clicked, since here you submit the form through the function it's logical.

Check this example:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Preview">
</form>
```

This behavior allow multiple submit action in a form.

__

On checkbox click simulate a click on the submit button instead of using `submit()`

Comment: OK, I could do that. I olready have a solution with checking $_SERVER global variable. So that' not the point, I'm just asking wether it's normal behaviour.

Comment: Added some more about the behavior.

Comment: Yes, I know this, I use multiple submitt buttons in the same form for diferentiating actions. Actually, I use <button> instead, since in <button> one can have name and value hidden. This is not possible with <input type="button"> because value is shown as button's label (specialy not convenient when one has a page in multiple languages)

Comment: In what standard is this defined? Also it seems the behavior is different for GET method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal. I have made some code for you to make it work:).
Add a class to your checkbox and submit button. And add the js code to your html or separate js file.

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="cb" onclick="submit()">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" name="search" value="Search">
</form>
```

It goes in this function when you click on the checkbox, it is seeing when its enabled and if it's so simulate a click on the submit button.

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       $(".sub").click();
    }
});
```