# How do I retrieve the value from a button in app.post?

Tags: javascript, express, post, button

I am trying to pass a simple json to the server using POST.  How do I retrieve the value on the server side?  In this case, the value is a stringified JSON [{"key": "value"}], which accounts for the [0] on the server.

UPDATED

index.html

```
<form id="form" method="POST" style="background-color:#92a8d1" style="font-size: 18px; font-family:verdana,arial,tahoma,serif;">
  <label for="data">Demonstrations:</label><br>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="button" id="b1" name='d1' value="This is a demonstration"/></li> 
      <li><input type="button" id="b2" name='d2' value="This is a demonstration"/></li>
    </ul> 
    <input type="submit" name="run" value="THIS IS THE VALUE I WANT TO RETRIEVE"></input> 
</form>
```

server.js

```
app.post(`/`, (req, res) => {  
  console.log(Object.values(JSON.parse(req.body)))
});
```

result

```
[]
```

ANSWER is described below by @IAmDranged

index.html

```
<input type="submit" name="run" value=JSON TO PASS></input>
```

server.js

```
console.log(Object.values(req.body))
```

Comment: From the [MDN page for an `<input type="submit" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) -- _"An `<input type="submit">` element's `value` attribute contains a `DOMString` which is displayed as the button's label. **Buttons do not have a true value otherwise.**"_ (Emphasis added).  SO-- it appears that for a standard `form` `POST` you can expect the `value` of the `submit` `input` itself _not_ to be transmitted-- you'll either need to submit with JS or maintain a different, separate `input` that contains that value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524789/submit-button-value-sent-only-when-clicked

Comment: @IAmDranged Thank you very much.  I think I am getting closer but still not there.  The odd thing is that I had the right answer yesterday, but due to a @#$@$#@ I lost it and cannot recreate the magic.  Based on your answer, I think I need to rename "id" -> "name"  but am getting "[]" on the server side. i.e. <input type="submit" name="run" value="Run"></input> && console.log(Object.values(req.body)) == []

Comment: Yes, in any case your button should have a name attribute for it to be part of the form serialization on the client side.

Comment: Note the body should by JSON-parsed already if you actually use a body parser middleware on the server. Try just console.log(req.body) or console.log(Object.values(req.body)).